# Is there a way to have even faster dot products using Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen, dot

So, I am using Eigen to perform matrix math on my own data structures, which encapsulate std::arrays. I essentially obtain the dot product as such:

```
Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<D, N, 1>> m1(my_array1.data());
Eigen::Map<const Eigen::Matrix<D, N, 1>> m2(my_array2.data());
return m1.dot(m2);
```

This is pulled from a templated class, hence the stand-ins for the matrix dimensions, but otherwise it's fairly straightforward. I noticed that I'm getting some overhead to create the maps, and then there is of course the cost of the actual dot product.

Overall, I'm very happy with Eigen's performance, it's definitely much faster than my previous naive implementation of a dot product. However, since my program uses dot products so heavily, I was wondering if any wizards out there had some tips to speed this up further. Dot products account for about 10% of my program's total runtime, so it would be a lot of bang for my buck optimization-wise. My only constraint is that my vectors still live in contiguous stack variables (I'm not married to std::array specifically, but I like how they're currently getting the job done).

So, any tips? Or is this about the best I can get?

Comment: And how much overhead did you notice using `Eigen::Map`? There shouldn't be any, when compiled in release mode. If you want to "speed up your dot products", you'd need to show more context.

Comment: Oh yes, there is pretty much no overhead in release mode! I'd accidentally run my profiler in debug. How much more context would you like? I'm running on Windows 10 using MSVC. I'm not at liberty to share much more of the code, since it's proprietary.

Comment: If dot products are so important in your code, you could try if there's an improvement if you calclate them using `std::inner_product()` instead of using Eigen's `.dot()`.

Comment: Wow, it's way faster! More than twice as fast in my case. I guess sometimes the simplest solution is the best one.